# try loc a column with list pandas - index not found

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fixed array e.g. `sort_by = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`. My dataframe looks like this, I have made `Column1` my index:

```
Column1 | Column2 | ...
   d         1         
   d         2
   b         3
   a         4
   a         5
   b         6
   c         7
```

I want to loc from the `sort_by` list to sort them, however, sometimes not all values of `sort_by` are in `Column` which results in index not found. How do I get it to "try" to the best of its ability?

```
s.set_index('mitre_attack_tactic', inplace=True)
print(s.loc[sort_by]) --> doesn't work
print(s.loc[[a,b,c,d]) --> does work however Column1 could have e,f,g
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. After "sorting", what is the final output/dataframe you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `pd.Categorical`

```
out = df.iloc[pd.Categorical(df.Column1,['a','b','c','d']).argsort()]
Out[48]: 
  Column1  Column2
3       a        4
4       a        5
2       b        3
5       b        6
6       c        7
0       d        1
1       d        2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` of `df.sort_values`. Idea is to create a value index dictionary from `sort_by` list then map the dictionary to column and sort by the resulted index.

```py
key = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(sort_by)}
df = df.sort_values('Column1', key=lambda col: col.map(key))
```

```
print(df)

  Column1  Column2
3       a        4
4       a        5
2       b        3
5       b        6
6       c        7
0       d        1
1       d        2
```

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-a-custom-sort-on-pandas-dataframe-ac18e7ea5320#:%7E:text=How%20to%20do%20a%20Custom%20Sort%20on%20Pandas,variables.%20...%205%20That%E2%80%99s%20it.%20...%206%20References) helps:

If you create your `sort_by` as a categorical:

```
sort_by = pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(["a","b","c","d","e","f"], ordered=True)
```

Then change your column to a categorical:

```
s['Column1'] = s['Column1'].astype(sort_by)
```

You can then sort it:

```
s.sort_values('Column1')
```

Answer (score 0):

### `index.intersection`

```
df.loc[pd.Index(sort_by).intersection(df.index)]
```

---

```
   Column2
a        4
a        5
b        3
b        6
c        7
d        1
d        2
```